# How do I extract Amazon reviews from HTML?

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I have been trying to write a perl script to scrap amazon and download product reviews but I have been unable to do so.
I have been using the perl modules LWP::Simple and HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath to achieve this.

For the HTML

```
<div id="revData-dpReviewsMostHelpfulAUI-R1GQHD9GMGBDXP" class="a-row a-spacing-small">
  <span class="a-size-mini a-color-state a-text-bold">
    Verified Purchase
  </span>
  <div class="a-section">
    I bought this to replace an earlier model that got lost in transit when we moved. It is a real handy helper to have when making tortillas. Follow the recipe for flour tortillas in the little recipe book that comes with it. I make a few changes

  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

I wanted to extract the product review. For this i wrote:-

```
use LWP::Simple;

#use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

# Take the ASIN from the command line.
my $asin = shift @ARGV or die "Usage: perl get_reviews.pl <asin>\n";

# Assemble the URL from the passed ASIN.
my $url = "http://amazon.com/o/tg/detail/-/$asin/?vi=customer-reviews";

# Set up unescape-HTML rules. Quicker than URI::Escape.
my %unescape = ('&quot;'=>'"', '&amp;'=>'&', '&nbsp;'=>' ');
my $unescape_re = join '|' => keys %unescape;

# Request the URL.
my $content = get($url);
die "Could not retrieve $url" unless $content;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $content);
my @data = $tree->findvalues('div[@class ="a-section"]');

foreach (@data)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
```

But I am not getting any output. Can anyone please point out my mistake?

Comment: You should stick with `uri_unescape` to remove character entities from HTML. A hash together with a global regex may be faster, but insignifcantly so compared with the time taken to recover the HTML from the internet. And `uri_unescape` is much cleaner and self-documenting.

Comment: Why scrape Amazon? You know they have a [product API](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-Amazon)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the XPath should be `'//div[@class ="a-section"]'` (extra **//** at the beginning of the expression to find the `div` anywhere in the HTML)

Answer (score 0):

As choroba has said, your XPath expression should start with `//` to look for *descendants* of type `div`. As it stands, you are searching for `<div>` elements at the root of the document, and there are none.

You are also looking for a `class` attribute that is *equal* to `a-section`, when in fact each `div` element's `class` attribute can contain multiple classes, like

```
class="a-section a-subheader a-breadcrumb celwidget"
```

and you want any one of them to be `a-section`.

There are a few ways around this. The most obvious is to use XPath *contains* to see if `a-section` appears anywhere in the class string, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $asin = 'B0031EJBI4';

my $url = "http://amazon.com/o/tg/detail/-/$asin/?vi=customer-reviews";

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new->parse(get $url);

my @nodes = $tree->findnodes('//div[contains(@class, "a-section")]');

say scalar @nodes;
```

which reports 60 such nodes in the page. This is the correct result, and you may not want to go any further, but the solution isn't a secure one as it will match nodes like

```
<div class="aaa-sections">
```

as well. To fix this properly you need to revert to the non-XPath `HTML::Element` method `look_down`, like this, which insists on a word boundary before and after `a-section`.

```
my @nodes = $tree->look_down(
  _tag => 'div',
  class => qr/\ba-section\b/,
);

say scalar @nodes;
```

Again, the result is the correct 64.

But even that solution won't allow for classes that begin or end with a non-word character like `-section`, because `/\b-section\b/` will never be found. The most general solution is to use a subroutine in the `look_down` criteria, like this, which splits the class string on whitespace (the `' '` is correct: don't change it for `/ /` or `/\s+/`) and builds the `%classes` hash that uses all the substrings as keys. Then the existence of an `a-section` class is simply the value of `$classes{'a-section'}`

```
@nodes = $tree->look_down(
  _tag => 'div',
  sub {
    return unless my $class = $_[0]->attr('class');
    my %classes = map { $_ => 1 } split ' ', $class;
    $classes{'a-section'};
  }
);

say scalar @nodes;
```

Once more the result with this page is 64, but this solution will work with any class string.

Answer (score -1):

```
use LWP::Simple;

#use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

# Take the ASIN from the command line.
my $asin = shift @ARGV or die "Usage: perl get_reviews.pl <asin>\n";

# Assemble the URL from the passed ASIN.
my $url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00R3DO58K/ref=s9_ri_gw_g74_i2?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-3&pf_rd_r=01F13XCKC1KBQAJ4EY87&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=1970558902&pf_rd_i=desktop";

# Set up unescape-HTML rules. Quicker than URI::Escape.
my %unescape = ('&quot;'=>'"', '&amp;'=>'&', '&nbsp;'=>' ');
my $unescape_re = join '|' => keys %unescape;

# Request the URL.
my $content = get($url);



die "Could not retrieve $url" unless $content;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $content);
my @data = $tree->findvalues('//span[@class="vtp-byline-text"]');


#print $content;

foreach (@data)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: A little narrative would be nice to explain your post.  And it suffers from the same problem as the OP's code: that it won't find `<span>` elements with multiple values in the `class` attribute.

Comment: And your `@data` array contains just four nodes, with the text `~ Matthew McConaughey ~ Ian McKellen ~ Jennifer Lawrence ~ Ian McKellen`. Not what the OP had in mind when he asked for reviews!

Comment: Just i have given in span element attribute contains `//span[@class="a-size-base review-text"]` it will give you the list of reviews... on current page results....